# Django ORM object sequence when using a list as filter condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Does Django ORM guarentee the filter sequence when we use a list as filter condition?

```
result = Model.objects.filter(id__in=id_list, user__id=user.id)
```

The id_list is like: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
Does the result always keep the sequence followed by id_list?

Where is the Django Document mention about this?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if the items in `result` will have the same order as the corresponding items in `id_list`? If so: no, the database doesn't guarantee that, and neither does Django. Without an explicit ordering using `order_by()`, the order is arbitrary.

Comment: @knbk 
" Are you asking if the items in result will have the same order as the corresponding items in id_list? " 
> YES

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
pk_list = [10, 2, 1]
clauses = ' '.join(['WHEN id=%s THEN %s' % (pk, i) for i, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
ordering = 'CASE %s END' % clauses
queryset = Model.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list).extra( select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))`
```